# Strings getting messed up within the loop

Tags: java

So guys, I've made a program that counts how many **words** and **letters** a given sentence has. For instance, if my input is "stack overflow", it would return *2 WORDS* and *13 LETTERS*. But I've been having a problem to read single letters that are also contained in another word within the sentence. For example, the input "a alex" has been returning me 2 words and **4 LETTERS**, when it should be returning 5 letters... I noticed that, as soon as it reads the first "a", the second string "alex" becomes "lex" for some reason, but I don't know how to solve it... here's the snippet, thx in advance!

```
package Uri;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class Facil{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            
            String lida=sc.nextLine();
            
            int letras=0, palavras=0;
       
            while(lida != ""){
                
                System.out.println("current sentence = " + lida);
                
                if (lida.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    lida = lida.replaceFirst(" ", "");
                    continue;
                }
                if (!lida.contains(" ")) {
                    palavras++;
                    letras+=lida.length();
                    System.out.println("quantity of added letters = " + lida.length());
                    break;
                }
                
                String separada = lida.substring(0,lida.indexOf(" "));
                System.out.println("separated word = " + separada);
                
                
                if (!separada.contains("..") && separada.endsWith(".") || !separada.contains(".")){
                    palavras++;
                    letras+=separada.length();
                    lida = lida.replace(separada, "");
                    System.out.println("added letters = " + separada.length());
        
                } 
            }
            System.out.println("\n RESULT: ");
            System.out.println("quantity of words = " + palavras);
            System.out.println("quantity of letters = " + letras);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick glance at your code and I found this `lida = lida.replaceFirst(" ", "");`.

Comment: that's for like, in case the read sentence is "         alex", it would take out the blank spaces.. could it be possibly causing the problem? (btw this code is for a coding competition, so it's not meant to be practical or anything)

Comment: AH! I just found the problem, it was related to the other replace, it should've been "replaceFirst". Thanks for commenting, it helped me to have a better glance at my code :)

Comment: `while(lida != "")`  is not how you compare strings in java

Comment: if you use `String#replace` and `String#split`, quantity of words is `lida.split(" ").length` and quantity of letters is `lida.replace(" ", "").length()` . Another approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from `lida = lida.replace(separada, "");` where you replace 'a' with space

How about using `lida.split(" ")` then get the length of the array for the number of words? And for each word, use `String.length()` to count for the letters?